# asp.net mvc Updating navigation collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I update navigation collection properties while keeping entity framework tracking?

Domain:

```
public class BuyLink
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    string _buyLinkUrl;
    public string BuyLinkUrl
    {
        get
        { return _buyLinkUrl; }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                _buyLinkUrl = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Dto:

```
public class BuyLinkDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string BuyLinkUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

For example,  `_songService.GetSong(editSongDto.Song.Id).BuyLinks` does get the current buyLinks with tracking, however, how do I update this collection with the user supplied edits from editSongDto.BuyLinks without losing this tracking change?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestEdit(EditSongDto editSongDto)
{
    //Doesn't work well because entity Framework doesn't track with this assignment so it adds to the database instead of updating.
    var buyLinks = _songService.GetSong(editSongDto.Song.Id).BuyLinks = editSongDto.BuyLinkDtos.Select(x => new BuyLink { BuyLinkUrl = x.BuyLinkUrl }).ToList();

    _songService.Edit(_songService.GetSong(editSongDto.Song.Id), editSongDto.AudioName, editSongDto.ArtistName, buyLinks);

      return View("Index");
}
```

Service:

```
public void Edit(Song song, string audioName, string artistName, IEnumerable<BuyLink> buyLinks)
{
    song.AudioName = audioName;
    song.ArtistName = artistName;
    song.BuyLinks = buyLinks?.ToList();

    _repository.Edit(song);
}
```

Repo:

```
public virtual void Edit(T entity)
{
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating an entity, you should always work on a fresh instance from the database, rather than creating a new instance and trying to overwrite the existing instance with that. In other words:

```
var song = _songService.GetSong(editSongDto.Song.Id);
var buyLinks = song.BuyLinks.ToList();

...

foreach (var buyLinkDto in editSongDto.BuyLinkDtos)
{
    var buyLink = buyLinks.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id != 0 && m.Id == buyLinkDto.Id);

    // New BuyLink
    if (buyLink == null)
    {
        buyLink = new BuyLink { BuyLinkUrl = buyLinkDto.BuyLinkUrl };
        song.BuyLinks.Add(buyLink);
    }
    // Existing BuyLink
    else
    {
        buyLink.BuyLinkUrl = buyLinkDto.BuyLinkUrl;
    }
}
```

Now, Entity Framework knows exactly what's going on, and will insert/update appropriately.